# Setting the post thumbnail from code fails

Tags: php, wordpress, thumbnails

I had a non-finished version for setting a post thumbnail from a base64 encoded image (from an API) which i dind't use at the time but now i need it.

```
function attach_image ( $base64, $post_id, $filename ) {

    if ( empty($base64) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $decoded = base64_decode($base64) ;
    $hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;

    $image_upload = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded );

    if( !function_exists( 'wp_handle_sideload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, $hashed_filename, $parent_id );

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $hashed_filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id, true);
}
```

This almost work,

- The images gets copied to the current wp-content/year/month folder
- The image has the hash prepended in the name ( `0acaa00c73c27baa3277ff22ba5acf05_xk35480.jpg` )
- The image is set as the post thumbnail (for the $post_id )

But the problem is that,
If the image saved is:

`wp-content/uploads/2019/09/0acaa00c73c27baa3277ff22ba5acf05_xk35480.jpg`

The post thumnail url is:

`wp-content/uploads/xk35480.jpg`

Note that the year, month and hash are lost. So obviously the thumbnail url returns 404

So the question is, can you spot the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work by prepending `wp_upload_dir()['path'].'/'` to the `wp_insert_attachment` and to the `wp_generate_attachment_metadata` functions but I wonder if it can be done "better"

```
function attach_image ( $base64, $post_id, $filename ) {

    if ( empty($base64) ) {
        return false;
    }

    $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
    $upload_path = str_replace( '/', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $upload_dir['path'] ) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;
    $decoded = base64_decode($base64) ;
    $hashed_filename = md5( $filename . microtime() ) . '_' . $filename;

    $image_upload = file_put_contents( $upload_path . $hashed_filename, $decoded );

    if( !function_exists( 'wp_handle_sideload' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/file.php' );
    }

    $wp_filetype = wp_check_filetype(basename($filename), null );
    $attachment = array(
        'post_mime_type' => $wp_filetype['type'],
        'post_title' => preg_replace('/\.[^.]+$/', '', basename($filename)),
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'inherit'
    );
    $attach_id = wp_insert_attachment( $attachment, wp_upload_dir()['path'].'/'.$hashed_filename, $post_id );

    $attach_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, wp_upload_dir()['path'].'/'.$hashed_filename );
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $attach_id, $attach_data );

    add_post_meta($post_id, '_thumbnail_id', $attach_id, true);
}
```